# Controller de área administrativa Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, framework, controller

Estou desenvolvendo um site com área administrativa. Comecei ele com a nova versão do Codeigniter 3.1.5.
Nas paginas principais ficaria corpo do site, já nas paginas de noticias a url ficaria a seguinte: `www.exemplo.com/noticia/visualizar/id` com o `controller` noticia e a função visualizar respondendo a url.

Já na pagina administrativa o link seria `www.exemplo.com/admin` com o `controller 
 admin` trazendo a pagina principal da área administrativa. A partir desta URL os controllers de adicionar noticias, fotos, etc. Devem responder a url por exemplo: `www.exemplo.com/admin/noticia/adicionar` com o `controller noticia` sendo posterior ao `admin` na url. Pensei em colocar dois Framework na hospedagem um na pasta raiz e outro em admin. Mais acredito não ser o melhor. Li sobre `extends class`, mais não sei se estou no caminho certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o seguinte, dentro da pasta `application/controllers` ([utilizando o conceito de controles em sub-diretórios via documentação](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories)) crie uma pasta com o nome de `admin`, exemplo `application/controllers/admin`, e agora todos os `controllers` que fizerem parte da área administrativa faça o arquivo ai dentro, exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e para chamar essa página no navegador faça assim:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

isso já garante inclusive o nome da rota. Os outros arquivos podem continuar da mesma forma, ou seja, na mesma pasta `application/controllers`.

Esse processo é bom também para organizar o seu código separando o que é administrativo e o que é para todos acessarem.

Se quiser criar uma rota padrão para essa pasta vai em `application/config/routes.php` e adicione no final do arquivo assim:

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/home/index';
```

sendo que ao cair na rota `admin` vai acessar por padrão o `controller` `Home` e o método `index`

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Controllers](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#controllers)
- [Organizing Your Controllers into Sub-directories](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories)
- [URI Routing](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Amigo tentei também assim e não deu certo, já que eu usava esse método no codeigniter 2.X, então procurei na net como fazer no 3.x e achei o que comentei na pergunta. Mais vou tentar denovo, talvez tenho passado batido em alguma coisa.

Comment: Só pra informar @WillianCoqueiro esse processo foi realizado na versão 3 talvez falte alguma coisa! entendeu? ele também funciona na 2

Comment: E então. Pelas suas referencias que me passou da documentação vi que realmente tem que dar certo. Incrível como li a documentação antes e não achei. kkk Achei que tinha despreciado da versão anterior ou foi correção de bug.

Comment: Poxa não da certo. Eu tenho `controllers/home.php, controllers/noticia.php, controllers/admin.php, controllers/admin/noticia.php, controllers/admin/foto.php`  e não da certo.

Comment: não da certo o que? o que acontece? @WillianCoqueiro se ta fazendo errado eu to achando (uma coisa admin.php e depois um pasta admin pode causar problemas)

Comment: Tem que avaliar suas rotas... por exemplo se não consegue entrar na rota `/admin/foto`

Comment: Agora tô pelo celular. Mais não consigo acessar direto. Realmente é o admin.php. Passou batido.  Amanhã Vo tentar.

Comment: Deu certo. Era a pasta admin conflitando com o arquivo admin.php dentro da pasta raiz do `controllers`